# Show drop down when hovered on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need code to make rollover images create dropdowns beneath them (of text) and return to the original image when the mouse is hovered off the dropdown OR off the original image.

Anyone have code to accomplish this? I've been altering code from this site all day and got really close just not totally there.

**Menu**

```
<table width="830px" border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 >
  <tr height="25px">
    <td valign="top" align="left"><a href="aboutus1.php"><img src="images/cti-logo.png"></a></td>

    <td valign="bottom" align="right"><a href="welcome.php">
    <img  src="images/home.jpg" onMouseOver="this.src='images/hover-home.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/home.jpg'"/>

    <a href="aboutus1.php"  target="content"><img id="id_About" onClick="over('about')"  src="images/aboutus.jpg"  onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-aboutus.jpg'" onMouseOut="if(me2=='about'){}else{this.src='images/aboutus.jpg'}" /></a>

    <a target="content" href="partners.php" ><img onClick="over('partners')" id="id_Partners" src="images/partners.jpg" onMouseOver="this.src='images/hover-partners.jpg'" onMouseOut="if(me2=='partners'){}else{this.src='images/partners.jpg'}" /></a>

    <a href="products1_1.php" target="content"><img onClick="over('products')" id="id_Products" src="images/products.jpg"  onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-products.jpg'" onMouseOut=" if(me2=='products'){}else{this.src='images/products.jpg'}" /></a>

    <a href="contactus.php" target="content"><img id="id_Contactus" onClick="over('contactus')" src="images/contactus.jpg"  onmouseover="this.src='images/hover-contactus.jpg'" onMouseOut=" if(me2=='contactus'){}else{this.src='images/contactus.jpg'}" class="contactus" /></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="bar"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: We do your homework???

Comment: No. I did a lot of workaround but none worked from any of it. I also tried searching but of no luck. Most of what I search in the net are text, in my case, I use image that's why I'm having very huge trouble how to make a drop down on image

Comment: Unfortunately I have already deleted my scratches of drop down from image.

Comment: @mohsin.mr, please try to edit posts thoroughly.  There were other issues like "?!?!".

Comment: Why have you tagged Jquery?

Comment: @AnaMaria, I was thinking that it could be done in JQuery, unfortunately I have a little knowledge on it.

Answer (score 0):

look at this JSFiddle. Hope this is what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/mohsin1303/RtMQh/

**HTML Code**

```
<html>
<head>
     <title>This is a demo using CSS Sprites</title>
     <style>
           .myButtonLink {
               display: block;
               width: 100px;
               height: 100px;
               background: url('http://www.justcode.us/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/buttonleafhover.png') bottom;
           }
           .myButtonLink:hover {
               background-position: 0 0;
           }

     </style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="myButtonLink" href="#LinkURL"></a>
</body>
</html>
```